# HTML: Sort a slightly complex table column

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have an HTML table which has 2 headers row:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <table id="res-table">
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">H1</th>
                    <th rowspan="2" onclick="sortTable(1)">H2</th>
                    <th colspan="2">H3</th>
                    <th colspan="2">H4</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">H5</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>A1</th>
                    <th>A2</th>
                    <th>A3</th>
                    <th>A4</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</th>
                    <td>2</th>
                    <td>3</th>
                    <td>4</th>
                    <td>5</th>
                    <td>6</th>
                    <td>7</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</th>
                  <td>21</th>
                  <td>31</th>
                  <td>41</th>
                  <td>51</th>
                  <td>61</th>
                  <td>71</th>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <script>
            function sortTable(n) {
              var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
              table = document.getElementById("res-table");
              switching = true;
              //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
              dir = "asc"; 
              /*Make a loop that will continue until
              no switching has been done:*/
              while (switching) {
                //start by saying: no switching is done:
                switching = false;
                rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                /*Loop through all table rows (except the
                first, which contains table headers):*/
                for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
                  //start by saying there should be no switching:
                  shouldSwitch = false;
                  /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
                  one from current row and one from the next:*/
                  x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[n];
                  y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[n];
                  /*check if the two rows should switch place,
                  based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
                  if (dir == "asc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                      //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                      shouldSwitch= true;
                      break;
                    }
                  } else if (dir == "desc") {
                    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                      //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                      shouldSwitch= true;
                      break;
                    }
                  }
                }
                if (shouldSwitch) {
                  /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
                  and mark that a switch has been done:*/
                  rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                  switching = true;
                  //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
                  switchcount ++;      
                } else {
                  /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
                  set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
                  if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
                    dir = "desc";
                    switching = true;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            </script>           
        </body>
    </html>
```

I need to sort couple of the columns by clicking their headers. For example, the second one and the last one.

So, I took the code example from :  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp

The script worked for simple tables, as in their example. But it doesn't work for me. I guess it is related to the rowspan attribute.

Is that correct? How can I adjust their code, or mine to sort the row spanned columns?

Thanks.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code. But isn't the table looks odd?

Comment: Ohh! Sorry.. Actually I'm a bit idiot and was unable to understand that H3 has two parts - A1 and A2 whereas H4 has A3 and A4. -_- Now, it's clear.

Comment: @IU5er. That's ok. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Can you use other libraries like jQuery and lodash in your implementation ?

Comment: @NikhileshShivarathri Actually my task is so simple, and concludes in building this table and enable sorting 2 of its columns, so I was hoping I could manage to do this without any special technologies. But if there is no option, I guess I would have to do so... Can you guide me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed one thing.

Start the loop from `i=2`, (follow the comments) as we have to skip row 1 and row 2 which are both headers.

The updated code:

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
 //start by saying: no switching is done:
 switching = false;
 rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
 /* *********** Loop through all table rows (except the
 first, which contains table headers): *********** */
 
 <!-- BUT HERE WE NEED TO SKIP THE SECOND ROW TOO -->
 <!-- make i=2 -->
 for (i = 2; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
   //start by saying there should be no switching:
   shouldSwitch = false;
   /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
   one from current row and one from the next:*/
   x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
   y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
   /*check if the two rows should switch place,
   based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
   if (dir == "asc") {
  if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
    //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
    shouldSwitch= true;
    break;
  }
   } else if (dir == "desc") {
  if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
    //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
    shouldSwitch= true;
    break;
  }
   }
 }
 if (shouldSwitch) {
   /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
   and mark that a switch has been done:*/
   rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
   switching = true;
   //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
   switchcount ++;      
 } else {
   /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
   set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
   if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
  dir = "desc";
  switching = true;
   }
 }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table border="1px" id="myTable">
     <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" onclick="sortTable(0)">H1</th>
    <th rowspan="2" onclick="sortTable(1)">H2</th>
    <th colspan="2">H3</th>
    <th colspan="2">H4</th>
    <th rowspan="2" onclick="sortTable(6)">H5</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th onclick="sortTable(2)">A1</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(3)">A2</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(4)">A3</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(5)">A4</th>
   </tr>
   
   <!--<tr>
     <th onclick="sortTable(0)">H2</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H2</th>
   </tr>-->
   <tr>
    <td>1</th>
    <td>2</th>
    <td>3</th>
    <td>4</th>
    <td>5</th>
    <td>6</th>
    <td>7</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>11</th>
     <td>21</th>
     <td>31</th>
     <td>41</th>
     <td>51</th>
     <td>61</th>
     <td>71</th>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad to know, I could help! :)

Comment: @IU5er, if you could also help me to understand how to apply numbers sorting and not only strings it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html). Although that was the first time ever I touched jQuery, it was a piece of cake using it!
Thank you all!